# Where is onScroll event in material ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I cannot find any documentation in [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) that shows a fired function for `onScroll`. All my components are either functional and stateless or container components which have the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` API.

How has anyone written Material UI `List` and `ListItem` components to also include scroll events for a function in `mapDispatchToProps` to run? There are click events, but no scroll events like `onScroll`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `onScroll` handlers on your own and the approach varies, depending on the default behavior of the component.

A component like [Drawer](https://material-ui-next.com/api/drawer/) can accept `onScroll` as a prop because its root element will scroll if the content is taller than the viewport and according to the docs:

> Any other properties supplied will be [spread to the root element](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/api/#spread).

Other components, like `List` and `ListItem`, which you've mentioned, do not scroll by default and would need to be wrapped in an element with an `onScroll` handler.

Answer (score -1):

when I was posed with same issue, all i did was used `getElementByXXX` to grab the specific tag in DOM and then do it the plain JS+DOM way. Specific implementation would vary depending upon what you want to achieve, with which component and your scenario. Hope this helps!